# Polymer 1.0 Data binding when object changes

Tags: migration, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm having trouble understanding how data-binding works now.

On my index page I've got an object (obtained as JSON from a RESTful service), which works just fine when applied to a custom element like:

```
<main-menu class="tiles-container ofvertical flex layout horizontal start" 
     menuitems="{{menuitems}}">
</main-menu>

var maintemplate = document.querySelector('#fulltemplate');
maintemplate.menuitems = JSON.parse(data.GetDesktopResult);
```

This works as expected, and when I load my page with different users, main-menu changes as it should to show each user's desktop configuration. (This `menuitems` object reflects position and size of each desktop module for each user).

Now, users used to be able to change their configuration on the go, and on Polymer 0.5 I had no problem with that, just changed my `maintemplate.menuitems` object and that was that, it was reflected on the template instantly.

As I migrated to Polymer 1.0, I realized changes on an object wouldn't change anything visible, it's much more complicated than this, but just doing this doesn't work:

```
<paper-icon-button id="iconback" icon="favorite" onClick="testing()"></paper-icon-button>

function testing(){
   debugger;
   maintemplate = document.querySelector('#fulltemplate');
   maintemplate.menuitems[0][0].ModuleSize = 'smamodule';
}
```

The object changes but nothing happens on the screen until I save it to DB and reload the page.

Am I missing something /Do I need to do something else on Polymer 1.0 to have elements update when I change an object passed as a property?

Before you ask, I've got those properties setted as `notify: true`, it was the inly thing I found different, but still doesn't work

Thanks for reading!

EDIT:

this is the code `menuitems` is used in:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{menuitems}}" as="poscol">
   <div class="positioncolum horizontal layout wrap flex">
       <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{poscol}}" as="mitem" index-as="j">
           <main-menu-item class$="{{setitemclass(mitem)}}"
               mitem="{{mitem}}"
               index="{{mitem.TotalOrder}}"
               on-click="itemclick"
               id$="{{setitemid(index, j)}}">
           </main-menu-item>
       </template>
   </div>
</template>
```

`main-menu-item` is just set of divs which changes size and color based on this object properties

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the mutation helper functions if you want to modify elements inside an object or array otherwise `dom-repeat` won't be notified about the changes (check the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-repeat)):

```
function testing(){
   debugger;
   maintemplate = document.querySelector('#fulltemplate');
   this.set('maintemplate.0.0.ModuleSize', 'smamodule');
}
```

Comment: Just tried that, the object changes as expected, but still doesn't do anything else...

Comment: Could it be a problem with computed class? As I read on the docs this should work, but it never goes into setitemclass(), which is where I change the item's class, and makes it change its size and looks.

Comment: is the `poscol` array a primitive array (only strings?). If so you might run into this [issue](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1839).

Comment: Is an array of objects, i'll look into this issue as soon as I can and see if that's my problem, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, at least it saved my day!! .set method do bind two-way.