# DOM doesn't update when property changes after migrating from Polymer 0.5 to 1.0

Tags: data-binding, polymer, dom-manipulation, polymer-1.0

I'm using `dom-repeat` to fill in the rows of a table, thusly:

```
<tbody>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{list}}" as="row">
        <tr>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{headers}}" as="header">
                <td><template is="juicy-html" content$="{{getPropertyByName(row, header.name)}}"></template></td>
            </template>     
        </tr>   
    </template>
</tbody>
```

where the `getPropertyByName()` function merely dereferences the row:

```
getPropertyByName: function (listObj, name) {
                    return listObj[name];
}
```

Before upgrading to 1.0, the function wasn't necessary as we could simply dereference directly, i.e. `content="{{row[header.name]}}"`.

We have a sort feature for the table which is triggered by clicking the table header, and prior to upgrading to 1.0 the data binding of `{{list}}` in the table row meant that sorting the elements of `this.list` in our JS function resulted in table rows moving in the DOM. Since Polymer 1.0 doesn't work that way, I'm not sure how I should alert Polymer that the property has changed, I tried using `this.set('this.list.0', this.list[0]);` following the sort, an idea I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844532/polymer-1-0-data-binding-when-object-changes), but that didn't work for me. How can I get Polymer to change the DOM after sorting my data-bound property in JS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `content="{{row[header.name}}"` will never work any way you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dom-repeat` has built-in support for sorting, there is documentation here https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#filtering-and-sorting-lists.

Basically you can attach a `sort` function (the same kind of function you would supply for `Array.sort`) to the template.

Also, you can call `render()` on the template to force a re-render.

Comment: This certainly sent me in the right direction, it's working now (without juicy-html, sadly). Thanks so much!

Comment: For the future delectation of anyone who may stumble upon this, [here](http://jsbin.com/kahaye/edit?html,console,output) is some example code Scott wrote using `dom-repeat`, `sort` and `render()`.

Comment: Just wondering, does the render function need to be called every time data changes? Is it temporary or something that has been changed since Polymer 0.5?

Comment: This [example code](http://jsbin.com/kahaye/edit?html,output) still looks to  be working (Polymer 1.6.1 as of today).

Answer (score 2):

To trigger a refresh you can call render() on the template.

```
this.$.templateID.render();
```

Comment: Thanks for the new knowledge! I updated the answer to reflect the correct way